# What should I do to repair the surface of this cast iron pan?

Tags: cast-iron, cookware, maintenance

I got this cast iron pan several years ago, and tried more than once to season it according to recommendations from articles I read. Each time, the process involved something like rubbing it with oil and sticking it in the oven, upside-down, for some amount of time. And each time, the pan came out not with a nice new seasoned surface, but just hot and wet.

So, I gave up and figured I'd acquire a seasoning naturally over time by cooking with it. And by now, I think I have - but the surface is highly pocked, and the sides are really rough and feel caked-up. In particular, there's a large section on the edge of the bottom  (on the left in this picture) that simply flaked off last year when I was scraping particularly aggressively to remove some burnt-on food.

[image: Picture of the pan]

What's the best thing to do for this pan? Should I strip the seasoning entirely somehow and start over?

Comment: Please at least use search before posting. This a very common question https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning-pans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you're not being brutal enough when cleaning the pan after each use, allowing deposits to build up over time. You should *always* scrape aggressively. You want a thin, tough layer, and that means removing anything that isn't tough.

I tend to scrub with a cloth, sponge, or plastic scouring pad to get the easily removed stuff off, wipe it dry, and then pour in a tablespoon or two of salt and thoroughly scrub with a paper towel using the salt as an abrasive; then rinse and dry. The pan should *not* be shiny when you're done cleaning it.

I rarely strip and reseason pans, unless they're rusty, but in this case it might be the most practical approach. Continuing to use it but cleaning more aggressively *might* sort things out over time, but in the process you'd have a patchy, flaky pan.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would strip it and start over -- you have some serious caked burnt oil and charcoal on that, and the seasoning is never going to "even out".  And probably use different instructions this time*.  Check the many questions linked by @Tetsujin in the comments.

(* judging just from that photo, I'd say you were using way too much oil. One seasoning "coat" should be like, 1-2 teaspoons of oil, no more)

Comment: 1-2 teaspoons of oil, of which about 0.9-1.9 teaspoons should be wiped off.  It is easy to leave too much oil on; it is impossible to leave too little on.